# Деплой приложения MERN-стек

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, развертывание, create-react-app

Всем привет)
Я работаю над приложением. Использую стек MERN (mongo, express, react, node). Сейчас у меня проблема как задеплоить все это. 
Моя структура проекта:

```
client/
 React_files...
server/
 Server_files...
```

Как правильно сделать деплой на сервер используя nginx. 
Помогите пожалуйста, буду благодарен любой помощи.
Спасибо

Comment: Т.е. необходим конфиг для NGINX?

Comment: Я настроил nginx, создал рут дерикторию для проекта. Простые html файли открываются под нужным доменом. Вопрос как в этой дериктории развернуть React приложение и сервер Express под него?